# Changing a field value on submit using a PHP variable

Tags: posts, forms

#### Preface:

Ok, I know people are going to tell me

> "use JavaScript"

To you people I'll say

> "No! I don't want to!"

but I have a valid reason:

#### Problem overview:

I have a plugin which automatically creates a post and assigns the category "YouTube" - and gives it the post type "Video" whenever a new video is uploaded to a YouTube channel.

But in order for the post to display correctly on the website the Video ID (`$_POST['_tern_wp_youtube_video']`) value needs to be placed in the `$_POST['pukka[_pukka_media_url]']` input field (after the standard YouTube stuff).

#### Where I've looked:

Everywhere that tells me it can't be done unless I use JavaScript - but like I said - I don't want to use JS because it's not really a visual thing I'm trying to fix - it's a database thing.

#### What I've tried:

I'm kind of half way through this. I've collected all the information I need, I just need to find the way to manipulate the other fields value (without JavaScript):

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'default_post_type' );
function default_post_type( $post_id ) {
    if ( in_category( 'YouTube' ) ) {
        // Change post_format to video
        set_post_format( $post_id, 'video' );

        // Get and combine values to create the YouTube watch URL
        $youtube_pre = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="; // Set the YouTube watch URL prefix
        $youtube_id = $_POST['_tern_wp_youtube_video']; // Get value of YouTube Video ID field
        $youtube_value = $youtube_pre.$youtube_id; // Combine the two
    }
}
```

So I've got the value that I want to enter (`$youtube_value`), but I can't figure out how to do it with PHP. I was thinking to use `str_replace()` - but that didn't work.

Comment: You really need to show us how your input is created. I don't even understand if you are fetching data from user input or just via an HTTP request (are you running some cron jobs to import data)...

Comment: totally not clear what is the actual problem you are having. The background story is just distracting, what do actually want to do and fail at?

Comment: On the create a post screen there is an input field called: "_tern_wp_youtube_video". This field value is automatically populated via the "Automatic Youtube Video Posts" plugin.
The post is automatically published (hence the "Automatic Youtube Video Posts" name) - so I need to take this value and input it into the field called "pukka[_pukka_media_url]" so that the post displays properly.